# Am I missing something in the requirements for an Electorate badge?

Tags: support

I've voted on over [600 questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5822/callithumpian) and nearly half of those votes were for the questions themselves, yet no Electorate badge.

> [Electorate](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/28/electorate): Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That badge is often misunderstood. You need to vote on 600 question posts, not on the answers to the questions.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. Back to the voting booth. . .

Answer (score 1):

So far, you voted on 309 questions, and 314 answers; you still need to vote on 291 questions. 
In that case, 65% of the votes would be on questions, as per badge requirements.